# EF Core saves null value of required property

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have three classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public string DOB { get; set; }
}


public class Teacher : Person
{

}
```

I want to make string DOB as required and I am doing this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasKey(d => d.Guid);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(d => d.DOB).IsRequired(true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

In SQL EF Core is generating nullable column:

[image: SQL]

And it is allowing to save data when DOB is null:

```
MainContext mainContext = new MainContext();
        mainContext.Add(new Student() { DOB = null });
        mainContext.SaveChanges();
```

[image: SQLResult]

However, It is working without inheritance. Is it an EF Core issue or I am missing something in model mapping?

**EDIT:** I replaced `DateTime?` to `string` because the issue is not related to the type of property

Comment: Please upvote EF Core issue [#2595](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/2595).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it an EF Core issue or I am missing something in model mapping?

It is indeed EF Core issue, which also is observed in the EFC 5.0 release candidate, so it won't be addressed (except if you change the database design to utilize TPT).

First, unlike EF6, EF Core does not perform validations in general. Instead, it relies on the underlying database to do that.

Second, since the TPH database inheritance strategy stores all data in a single table, the derived entity data columns must allow null, even though they are required, otherwise you won't be able to store `Teacher` entity data for instance.

The combination of the two aforementioned behaviors leads to the unexpected behavior of allowing null value for the required field of a derived entity.

Therefore there is nothing you could do at mapping side (neither fluently nor with `[Required]` data annotation). The necessary validations should be performed by the business logic layer outside the EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

> Please don't suggest me to make it DateTime DOB.

I am going to suggest just that, define DOB as:

```
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

EF Core uses [Table-per-hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration) here. It is clever enough to figure out that required properties on child types need to be NULL in the database because it needs to be able to store other childs (Teacher) and the base type (Person) where the required property is missing.

I think you are trying to solve a problem that is solved in EF Core itself.

Comment: The issue is not related to the type of property. I edited my question. Yes, you are right required properties must be null in SQL, BUT should EF Core allow to save the null value of required properties???

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to fix?

Comment: I am not sure what the expected behavior is in this case. You initially had a `DateTime?`, the type there indicates you want to specifically allow nulls else you could have just gone with the value type. Then you turn that around in your modelBuilder and say the property is actually required. I would not know what EF Core should do here.

Answer (score -2):

I think your property will be null when no value is present and your Required attribute will behave as expected. try to add Required as an annotation on prop maybe work